# Passed Modeltype of IEnumerable(of T) members are not recognized in Razor pages

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

I have a MVC 5 project which I created in an older version of Visual Studio and have opened in VS2019.  It complies fine but my view pages are seeing errors from the Model which is IEnumerable(of T).  For example, `If Model.Count > 0 Then` tells me "Count" is not a member of IEnumerable(of T).  Also, `Model.FirstorDefault` gives the same error.  I tried updating the packages in NuGet but to no success.  What am I missing here?  This is a completely valid and working project before opening in VS2019.

I have abbreviated the code to just the model in question

Repo:

```
Public Function GetFilesByTagID(ByVal tagID As Integer) As IEnumerable(Of File)
        Dim Files As IEnumerable(Of File)
        Files = From p In archiveDB.Files
                Where p.Tags.Any(Function(t) t.TagID = tagID)
                Select p

        Return Files
    End Function
```

Controller:

```
Private ar As New ArchiveRepository
Function Index(ByVal tagID As Integer) as ActionResult       
   Return View(ar.GetFilesByTagID(tagID))
End Function
```

Razor Page:

```
@Modeltype IEnumerable(Of Intranet.File)
<h2>
    Archives
    @If Model IsNot Nothing Then
    If Model.Count > 0 Then
            @<small>
                @Model.FirstOrDefault.Tags.Where(Function(t) t.TagID = CInt(Request.QueryString("tagID"))).FirstOrDefault.Name
            </small>
        End If
    End If
</h2>
```

Comment: Can you provide code for your razor page and also the action method used for this page?

Comment: An `IEnumerable<T>` has no `Count` property. It has, through Linq, an extension _method_ named `Count()`. If `FirstOrDefault()` gives the same error, there's something noot right with your `System.Linq` registration in your project.

Comment: I've added some of the code - which is currently working fine.  But now I need to make some edits and have to use VS2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by running Visual Studio as an Administrator.  Thanks Windows 10.  Can anyone explain why this is an issue for an existing project and not a new one?